# Camunda Test Deployment Annotation does not deploy

Tags: java, junit, camunda

I have an interface that wraps the camunda process engine. Now I want to test this wrapper like so

```
    @Test
    @Deployment
    public void canGetProcessDefinitions() {
        List<MyProcessDefinition> processDefinitions = 
                myProcessEngine.getProcessDefinitions();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, processDefinitions.size());
    }
```

I have a file next to my testfile called `MyProcessEngineTest.canGetProcessDefinitions.bpmn20`.

Now this test gives me an assertion error 1 != 0, because there is no deployment stored in the database (I checked by debugging into h2).

But if I add the file in my `@Before` method with a DeploymentBuilder the test works just fine, with the problem that now my deployment does not get purged after each test.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name must end on `.bpmn20.xml` or `.bpmn`, or else it will not be interpreted as BPMN during the deployment.